# VB.NET Gives error sometimes with custom fonts

Tags: vb.net

I have a problem, that VB.NET throws an error runtime with my custom fonts, but not always. Sometimes it works, sometimes not. here's my code:

```
Dim path As String

Private Sub MMenu_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    path = "C:/MMCTools/"
    Try
        Dim privateFonts As New System.Drawing.Text.PrivateFontCollection()
        privateFonts.AddFontFile(path & "font.ttf")
        Dim font20 As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 20)
        Dim font14 As New System.Drawing.Font(privateFonts.Families(0), 14)
        Label1.Font = New Font(font20, FontStyle.Regular)
        Label2.Font = New Font(font14, FontStyle.Regular)
    Catch
        MsgBox("Hiba")
    End Try
    If My.Computer.FileSystem.FileExists(path & "username.mcusr") Then
        PictureBox1.ImageLocation = _
          "http://mestermc.hu/3dskin/3d.php?a=0&w=0&wt=0&abg=0&abd=0&ajg=0&ajd=0&ratio=13format=png&displayHairs=true&    headOnly=false&login=" _
          & (ReadALine(path & "username.mcusr", GetNumberOfLines(path & "username.mcusr"), 0))
    Else
        MCUsr.Show()
        Me.Close()
    End If
End Sub
```

The error message:

```
************** Error contents **************
System.ArgumentException: Invalid parameter.
at: System.Drawing.FontFamily.GetName(Int32 language)
at: System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_Name()
at:     System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsFont.FromFont(Font font,     WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
at:     System.Windows.Forms.Internal.WindowsGraphicsCacheManager.GetWindowsFont(Font    font, WindowsFontQuality fontQuality)
at:     System.Windows.Forms.TextRenderer.MeasureText(String     text, Font font,     Size proposedSize, TextFormatFlags flags)
at:         System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutUtils.MeasureTextCache.GetUnconstrainedSize    (String text, Font font, TextFormatFlags flags)
at:    System.Windows.Forms.Layout.LayoutUtils.MeasureTextCache.TextRequiresWordBrea    k(String text, Font font, Size size, TextFormatFlags flags)
at:     System.Windows.Forms.Label.CreateTextFormatFlags(Size constrainingSize)
at: System.Windows.Forms.Label.CreateTextFormatFlags()
at: System.Windows.Forms.Label.OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
at:     System.Windows.Forms.Control.PaintWithErrorHandling(PaintEventArgs e, Int16     layer)
at: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmPaint(Message& m)
at: System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
at: System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
at:    System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
at:     System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
at: System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam
```

This happens when fast switching forms.

Comment: Could you please write it in English so we can understand it!!

Comment: Translated to english

Comment: System.Drawing starts throwing flaky exceptions when your app leaks resources.  Easy to do by forgetting to Dispose() them.  Like you do here btw.  Using a memory profiler to find the leaks is strongly recommended.

Comment: I disposed everything before switched forms, but did'nt fix it.

Answer (score 1):

Just came across the error myself and figured it out.  You are defining the private font collection in the load event and it goes out of scope thereby making it eligible for garbage collection.  So depending on how fast it gets collected it may or may not still be around when needed.

Comment: Thank you! That was actually my problem as well

Answer (score -2):

I've got your mistake here!!!! It's very easy to solve.
Path most be written with "\" not "/" that's all of it ^^
path = "C:\MMCTools\"

Comment: Is the file name written font.ttf or something else?

Comment: It's C:/MMCTools/font.ttf

Comment: Try to either change the path of the file to a path where does not require administrator or running your application without debugging as administrator

Comment: Doesn't work with Administrator access too. This error shows up like 1 in 50 runs.

Comment: OK, here is a workaround (kind of). Replace catch with Catch ex As Exception      and msgbox("hiba") with msgbox(ex.tostring). And then tell me what shows up.

Comment: That will not work because Catch never gets invoked. That's something else here

Comment: Could you please upload the font file in some upload center and give it to me. I'll try my best ^^ After all why we're here ^^

Comment: The problem occurs sometimes i switch 2 forms  http://89.133.232.237/N%C3%A9vtelen.png

Comment: I don't know what to say, but let's hope it won't show up a lot!

Comment: What about the image i sent? What's that red x at the place of my label?

Answer (score -2):

I'll tell you how you do it. Don't actually import the fonts into your program but import it on to your computer. 
 
Just access the:

> Control Panel -> Appearance and Personalization -> Fonts

And drag the fonts into the folder. Next time, Visual Studio will load the font. This is for windows. If you are using another computer, search how to load fonts onto computer.

Comment: This is not possible as a programming solution. You cannot go clicking that in for a thousands of end users. As a minimum, you'd have to provide a programatical way to do that. However, the OP asked for a different thing anyway.